# Measure Clock Drift On Linux Server, PTP/NTP Clock Reference

Tags: linux, clock, ntp, drift

Guys,

I got a task to measure the clock drift between a linux server and an "accurate" NTP/PTP server.

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `ntpdate` in debug mode (i.e. don't actually update the time). Also, this isn't really about programming...

Comment: how do you want to monitor? mrtg etc? or just a log file?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this that I used recently.

On your linux server on which you want to monitor drift you set up the NTP config file with a single server entry to your "accurate NTP/PTP server" and include the server option *noselect*.

When you run NTP it will not discipline the clock but the offset can be viewed using e.g. `nptq -pn` or `-c rl` and you can use that to determine the drift over time.